# How to find which file to translate in Magento

Tags: magento, translation, php

I'm trying to translate elements of my home page in magento. I have copied this core from "Inspect Element" option in Mozilla and is it possible from this code to tell me which phtml file I have to search for. I'm a noob, so I'm really sorry if I don't ask correctly my question, but somebody can help and need more info, I will provide it. Thank you in advance!

```
<head></head>
<body class=" cms-index-index cms-home">
    <div class="header-bg"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <noscript></noscript>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="main-container col1-layout">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <div class="std">
                            <div id="deal-58" class="deal div0">
                                <h3></h3>
                                <div class="pre photo"></div>
                                <div class="price-info"></div>
                                <div class="extra" style=""></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="deal-48" class="deal div1"></div>
                            <div id="deal-43" class="deal div2"></div>
                            <div id="deal-52" class="deal div0"></div>
                            <div id="deal-49" class="deal div1"></div>
                            <div id="deal-59" class="deal div2"></div>
                            <div id="deal-57" class="deal div0"></div>
                            <div id="deal-56" class="deal div1"></div>
                            <div id="deal-55" class="deal div2"></div>
                            <div id="deal-54" class="deal div0"></div>
                            <div id="deal-53" class="deal div1"></div>
                            <div id="deal-42" class="deal div2"></div>
                            <div id="deal-47" class="deal div0"></div>
                            <div id="deal-46" class="deal div1"></div>
                            <div id="deal-45" class="deal div2"></div>
                            <div id="deal-44" class="deal div0"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-container"></div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what you want to translate

Comment: This is the link to the website - http://ofertinio.com/ . I wanna translate the small boxes that appear when you go over with the mouse and they show countdown timer, buy, view buttons and down under the photo I have price info (Value, Discount, Price). This is what I wanna translate, but can't find which file controls them.

Comment: enable the path hint, then you can see which phtml is that

Answer (score 0):

For most core Magento text (and well-written extensions), you can do this without touching any files.  In the admin area, go to configuration - Developer - Translate Inline.

If this is a live site, make sure you fill in the "Developer Client Restrictions IPs" so that only you can see and edit it.  You can then edit text content on-the-fly.

If this does not allow you to edit the text, then you may need to update the specific file.  You can find where these files are likely to be by turning on "Template Path Hints", also under configuration - developer.  If this isn't an option, then you may need to select the store from the "current configuration scope" dropdown at the top-left of the page.  As always, don't edit core code.  Magento has a nice over-rides system for that.

Oh, and first of all make sure it isn't just editable in the admin area, of course.  I have been known to spend ages looking in the code for something that already exists in admin.

Comment: Hi, yes it does not allowe me to edit it with the integreted option in magento. I will try with this temlapte path hints. I can find this in admin panel, right?

Comment: They are under configuration - developer too, though you may need to select the shop under the "current configuration scope" for the option to appear.

Comment: Thank you...it work and it will do the job. Thank you very mich!